# SIGABORT when reading file into double pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, ifstream, sigabrt

I get `SIGABORT` when running this code. 
I discovered that I am suppose to use square brackets but why the behavior is same.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double * dp  = new double (5); // what do round brackets mean, and why the behvior

    std::ifstream fid("testdata.txt");
    fid >> dp[0] >> dp[1] >> dp[2] >> dp[3] >> dp[4];
    fid.close();
}
```

Content of "testdata.txt" is:

`4.0 5. 6. 6. 8. 7. 952.`

This error happens only when there is 5 or more doubles in file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [something about c++ "new"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797926/something-about-c-new)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
new double(5);
```

to

```
new double[5];
```

The first syntax creates one double on the heap and sets it to 5. The second syntax creates an array of five doubles.

Either way, it is a good practice to delete `dp` when you're done with it. In the first case, the correct syntax is `delete dp;` and in the second, `delete[] dp;`.

Comment: why does it SIGABRT on fid.close(), when there are 5 or more entries in "testdata.txt"

Comment: The behaviour of the `double(5)` version is undefined, so anything can happen. What likely happens in practice is that you have corrupted some part of `fid`.

Comment: @aiao The memory allocator does not necessarily allocate exactly `sizeof(double)` when you call `new double(5)`, so you were very lucky that you detected the buffer overflow. With a different allocator the error may have gone unnoticed. There are utilities such as **valgrind** that can help you detect errors like these.